# IP address in network different for LAN and Wireless

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, ip, lan

Hey all i have a LAN network IP addresses as 192.168.9.xxx. When i connected my router to the network i can only configure it to be 192.168.1.xxx but all of it works. I have internet for my .9.xxx address and wireless .1.xxx address.

The problem being is that i want to VNC into the wireless PC that has a ip address of 192.168.1.65. And since my computer on the network is 192.168.9.45 it wont connect to it. What do i need to do in order to get this to connect?

I already port forward ports 5800, 5500, 5900 & 3389 on the router for ip address 192.168.1.65.

Any help would be great!

Visuals of my current router settings:
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Is it possible to add a satic route in your router? (don't laugh, there are simple routers out there where it's not possible :)

Edit: Nevermind. Saw your comments with laurent.

Comment: Yes i could do that but i want to auto assign IP's on wireless.

Comment: with the suggestion I added below, you'll have auto IP on wifi, now you sent the screens, I will modifify to say where you need to change

Comment: @StealthRT - OK suggestion updated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming the router for `192.168.9.0` network is the same as `192.168.1.0` network, you need to define a static route on your router to access the 192.168.1.0 network. The gateway is your router IP in `192.168.1.0` network.

Being already there, you could also define a static route for `192.168.9.0` network if you need it.

**Edit** after comment:

If the main router is the pc, the wifi router is connected to it wired (wan port probably) so you need to set the static route on the PC and use the wifi router ip (in 192.168.9.0 network) as gateway.

**Suggestion:**

If you want all your ips in the 192.168.9.0 network, you can connect the wifi router to your PC using the LAN port instead of the WAN port and disable DHCP on it.

To do that you need to:

- 1st screen - Internet IP address: use get dynamically from ISP
- 3rd screen: use IP 192.168.9.101 in LAN TCP IP setup (not sure it is needed but it won't make any problem)
- 3rd screen: disable use router as DHCP server
- Unplug the wire from WAN port and connect to any LAN port

This way the netgear wifi router will receive an IP from the DHCP (PC) and will forward DHCP packets to and from the wifi devices so they will receive an IP from the PC too. 
All the machines will be in the same subnet and you will be able to connect any machine to any other (including printers or other devices) without using a more complicated setup using 2 subnets.

**OBS:**
192.168.9.0 doesn't mean the ip of the router but the subnet 192.168.9.xxx

Comment: I'm using PDANET to connect to the internet via Verizon cell phone. My desktop in another room is a dedicated PC just for the connection to the internet which is what is passing the 192.168.9.xxx ip address throughout the network in the house. I hooked up the router to that network and thats where i am getting the 192.168.1.xxx ips from (wireless). The gateway and DNS is 192.168.9.1 for the PC with the PDANET running.

Comment: But why would the router need a ip of 192.168.9.0 if the main PC is the 192.168.9.1 home?

Comment: And yes, i currently have the router connected via WAN to the 8 port switch. I wanted the router to auto assign wireless IP's so i didn't have to manual set a computer to a static address.

Comment: if the router is connected to the PC, it needs (and have) an IP in the same network as the PC (192.168.9).

Comment: Check the updated OP please :o)

Answer (score 0):

All connected networks to the same router, don't need routing. As long as you have the correct gateway, and taking that this is not a dumbass wannabe router,  there is no need for static routes.